# How to update the first page from the second redirected page?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have two pages :

```
page1.aspx

page2.aspx
```

The first one has a `GridView` which open the second page .

I want to open the second page and when submit it updates the `Gridview` in the first page to reflect the changes  .

---

```
protected void gv_inbox_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
   int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);


    if (e.CommandName == "sign")
    {
      Session["main_code"] = int.Parse(((HiddenField)gv_inbox.Rows[index].Cells[1].FindControl("HDN_MainCode")).Value);
      Session["year"] = int.Parse(((HiddenField)gv_inbox.Rows[index].Cells[1].FindControl("HDN_Year")).Value);
      Session["values_key"] = gv_inbox.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString();

     String js = "window.open('page2.aspx', '_blank');";
                ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Open Signature.aspx", js, true);

     }
}
```

I want when click on the `button [Confirm]` in the `page2.aspx` to update the first page .
and close the second page

Comment: Can't you just redirect and reload the data or are you trying to do this with AJAX?

Comment: How do mean *updating the first page*? Are both pages opened in separate windows/tabs or should `page1` be updated when navigating back to it from `page2`?

Comment: i mean update the data in the first page . say i have 3 records in the grid view and i confirm the first record . so the grid view should have two records instead of three ..

Comment: i prefer a solution with `Ajax`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some form in the second page on submission of which you want to show newly submitted data into the gridview? If this is the case, on submit of first form, you should just reload the page1.aspx.

SO to do this: simply use js trick "self.parent.location.href=self.parent.location.href;" on click of button [Confirm].

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to put a button on page 2 that redirects again to page 1. Another option is to have a timer that after a few second it will go back to page 1.